# Swap position of poster and editor on mobile app

Tags: feature-request, design, ios-app, mobile-app

Across the Stack Exchange network, the original poster appears in the lower right, with any edits then appearing to the left of that.

I'm not sure when it changed, but the mobile app (iOS, v 1.6.3.6) seems to be displaying this information in a different way to how it used to; the original poster is now on the left, with any edits being shown on the right.

It's a minor thing, but not having it consistent with the network means my eye is drawn to the wrong person a lot of the time.  The latest one being a comment on a Q saying "welcome to stack...", and a brief moment of confusion because the asker had 4k+ of rep.  Only they weren't the asker, they were an editor...

[image]

Can these elements be swapped over please?